# Best way to handle clicks on buttons in JavaScript (vanilla)

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, target

Edit: My question might have been overly broad (still learning), but I nevertheless received very useful answers. So thank you all very much for your input. I've also corrected my code to incorporate passing on 'event'.

---

This is my first question asked here, so I'm a bit nervous...

Here we go: What are the best ways (regarding best practise, speed, compatibility and so on) to manage clicks on buttons and let them trigger different functions?

When researching this question, I found an example on [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html#h_NEhx0cDpml) and took this as a basis.

Then I extended it, by using a “mapper” (is this the correct term?) to find the right function, depending on the id of the button who is triggering the event.

Here’s the code:

```js
// functions I want to trigger
function one(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + e.textContent);
}

function two(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + e.textContent);
}

// mapper object to hold my functions
var buttonMap = {
  b_one: function(event) {
    one(event.target)
  },
  b_two: function(event) {
    two(event.target)
  }
}

// Event Listener
var buttonClick = document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    var tar = event.target.id;
    buttonMap[tar](event)
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="b_one" type="button">Button One</button>
<button id="b_two" type="button">Button Two</button>
```

Is this solution ok? How can it be improved? Are there any problems I could run into?

Little bonus question: Additionally, I thought about wrapping the whole thing inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {})`.

Is this a good idea or even needed? In what cases should I check if the DOM content is loaded and when can I omit this check?

Comment: Setting the eventListener on the body might be quite heavy since every click everywhere will trigger your method.

Comment: @Pete - event delegation. Now he can add and remove buttons without the need to add/remove event listener each time.

Comment: This is how jQuery event delegation works (`on`) - you attach an event handler to a container, and designate the children to that will trigger the event handlers when interacted.

Comment: @Pete It's **not** expensive, certainly not more than adding event listeners on several different elements. The browser will propagate the event through the entire node tree regardless and having only a single handler function on a single node is beneficial.

Comment: This question is overly broad and promotes largely opinion based answer. Due to this it is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the help sections on what question are OK to ask. You could also consider asking on [codereview.se] but I suggest you make sure you check out their rules on posting first, to make sure your question fits on there

Comment: @musefan: I'm sorry your first comment has disappeared. No idea how this has happened. I actually had to think about the “sheep will be sheep” expression for a moment (not native English speaker). You mean like “someone upvotes, so others will follow without questioning their actions”?

Comment: @musefan Anyway, thanks for your explanation as to why you consider my question not suitable. Do you have suggestions on what parts I should be more specific on or do you feel it's not a good fit in general?  Tbh, it’s not that easy to phrase a good question when there are still so many knowledge-gaps, missing terminology and lack of grasping some basic concepts. But I will ponder a bit on this and try to do better in the future. Maybe even try to edit this question.

Comment: Btw: thanks for all the answers, even if I can improve my question-posing-skills ;)

Some comments seem to have been deleted, but thank’s @msanford for your edit - very cool!

Comment: @sjahan  Would you consider it a better idea to have a parent element (container) just around the area where the buttons are and monitor this instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a simple event delegation that will give you the ability to add/remove buttons without the need to add/remove event handlers.

If you've got a lot of buttons that you create or destroy dynamically, it's better to use event delegation, than pay the cost of manually managing the handlers.

You can put the event handling code at the end of your body, instead of using the `DOMContentLoaded` event. As long as the container (`body` in this case) exists, it doesn't matter if the children exist or not.

Attach the global event handler to the closest container, and not to the body if you can. In addition, use `data-*` attributes instead of the `id` or the `value` attribute to add data to the buttons. An `id` creates a global variable, and value will be used in forms.

```
<div class="buttonsContainer">
  <button type="button" data-value="one">Button One</button>
  <button type="button" data-value="two">Button Two</button>
</div>
```

You should pass the event object to the event handler:

```
var buttonClick = container && container.addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
      var target = event.target;
      var handler;
      if (target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && (handler = target.getAttribute('data-handler'))) {
        buttonMap[handler](event)
      }
    });
```

Demo:

```js
function one(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + e.textContent);
}

function two(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + e.textContent);
}

// mapper object to hold my functions
var buttonMap = {
  b_one: function(event) {
    one(event.target)
  },
  b_two: function(event) {
    two(event.target)
  }
}

// Event Listener
var container = document.querySelector('.buttonsContainer');
var buttonClick = container && container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var handler;
  if (target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && (handler = target.getAttribute('data-handler'))) {
    buttonMap[handler](event)
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="buttonsContainer">
  <button type="button" data-handler="b_one">Button One</button>
  <button type="button" data-handler="b_two">Button Two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: . I agree, I probably should have put the buttons inside a container, that’s a good way to improve my example - thanks for the input. 
. As for placing the code at the end as you and @Mikael Lennholm have mentioned - it’s definitely something to put into consideration.
. If ‘id’ produces a global variable, should I try to only set ids where absolutely neccessary and always prefer custom data* attributes?

Comment: . I see you assign the handler variable inside the if statement - is this for error-handing reasons?
. Is there a specific reason you use .querySelector to get the container? Wouldn’t .getElementById probably be faster or do you prefer this, because you want to omit setting ids (as mentions above)?

Comment: You should avoid using ids as much as possible. In this case `data-*` is better because you wish to assign to the element data about the handler. I'm assigning the handler inside the `if` because I want to check if it has the attribute and assign it only for buttons (and it's not that important :-). I prefer not to use ids, and `querySelector` will give you a single element when you query a class.

Comment: Thank you for the great input. Btw: Based on your hint with the data-* attribute, I did some more research and just discovered this (https://codepen.io/stowball/post/writing-a-generic-event-handler-with-data-attributes-and-a-simple-javascript-method) article by Matt Stow. I do like his approach too.

Comment: That's nice. It's a step towards declarative event handling. However, if you wish to be declarative, you should see how angular/react/vue/etc... frameworks handle event handling.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, thank you. For the time being, I wanted to stay with vanilla JS, so I can fully understand how things work. And I have a feeling, I have still a long way to go.

Comment: Welcome, and good luck with your studies :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you may also consider to use the `onClick` HTML attribute.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('hey!');
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">Do something</button>
```

It's probably old fashion but it's damn easy to understand and maintain, and it's just what happens nowadays with libraries like React*.

*: well, not really, but the API is similar.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't like it. You have answered a broad, opinion based question, with your opinion. So I should vote based on if I agree with your opinion or not

Comment: It's not an opinion, it's just an alternative. And downvotes are not meant to be used for "I don't like it". Also, you shouldn't abuse your powers to delete comments arbitrary

Comment: You're suggesting a practice that has been discouraged (for very good reasons) since 15 years back. What React and similar libraries do just look superficially similar but is completely different.

Comment: It has been discouraged before people understood that having JS and HTML together was actually a good thing.

Comment: @FezVrasta: I don't have the power to delete comments (I don't even know who does... moderators maybe, or even higher than that?). Alternatives offer multiple approaches to which the choice of which to use is based on opinion. And unfortunately, there is no other criteria to vote on in this instance, other than if I agree with your approach or not

Comment: It's still very much discouraged, one of the most important reasons being that it requires pollution of the global namespace. React, Vue, etc. don't have that problem because of their module based approach. They don't have "JS and HTML together", they have JS together with their own proprietary template language.

Comment: I actually had something like that at the beginning of my little “project” (I was using a very old JavaScript book as my source of knowledge), but than came to the understanding, that it is preferable to keep HTML and JavaScript as separate as possible. But it’s true that it’s - at first - easier to understand than .addEventListener ;)

Answer (score 1):

The mapper function really doesn't add much to this, other than add layer of abstraction that could become useful in dynamic DOM environments.

However, if you know in the mapper which function goes with which button, you can just register the functions with the respective buttons directly.

Also, be aware that when you register an anonymous function as an event callback, you won't be able to use `.removeEventListener()` to de-register the callback later. That doesn't mean using anonymous functions for events is a deal-breaker, but it's something to consider.

Note that you had a couple of HTML and JavaScript issues that are explained in the comments:

```js
document.getElementById("b_one").addEventListener("click", one);
document.getElementById("b_two").addEventListener("click", two);

// The e parameter represents the event object itself. It won't
// have any textcontent. But, in a DOM event handler, "this" will
// refer to the element that triggered the event and that's where
// the textContent is.
function one(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + this.textContent);
}

function two(e) {
  alert("You clicked " + this.textContent);
}
```

```html
<!-- You typically won't give a <button> element a "value"
     attribute. The content within the element is usually 
     what you need. -->
<button id="b_one" type="button">Button One</button>
<button id="b_two" type="button">Button Two</button>
```

Now, if your callback function requires parameters, you'll need to wrap it in another function that becomes the main callback and that function can then call your actual function, sending it the parameters it may need, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("b_one").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  // The actual callback will automatically recieve a reference to the
  // event that triggered it, so it's a good idea to pass that along
  // to the main function so that the DOM object and details about the 
  // event can be used along with any other custom arguments you require.
  one(evt, new Date().toLocaleTimeString()); 
});

function one(e, d) {
  console.log("The event was: " + e.type);
  console.log("It happened at: " + d);
  console.log("The text of the element was: " + e.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<!-- You typically won't give a <button> element a "value"
     attribute. The content within the element is usually 
     what you need. -->
<button id="b_one" type="button">Button One</button>
```

Comment: The way the code is written, `this` will be `window` inside the `one()` and `two()` functions, since they are not the actual event handlers but rather invoked (without context) by the actual event handler. The even of they were the event handlers, `this` would be `document.body` (since that's where the event listener is added) instead of `event.target` as desired.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I don't know what answer you're looking at, but none of what you say pertains to my answer above. My code is registering the `one` and `two` functions as event handlers for the `click` events of the buttons. The invocation context for the functions will be the DOM object that was clicked. And, of course, you can simply run the code snippet above to see that it works as it should.

Comment: Right, the way you wrote it. Sorry, at first I didn't realize that you completely removed the event delegation approach.

Comment: @Scott Marcus 
. Abstracting was actually something I wanted to achieve, as I think it will make my code-snippet more reusable for different scenarios. 
. The other thing I was trying to do, is to set as few eventListeners as possible. My project will have a list of objects that I want to manipulate with the different buttons (e.g. loading them into a form to edit, delete them, sort them). And somehow I imagined it less “heavy” to have a single eventListener instead of potentially dozens for every element. Or is the latter way preferable and if yes, why?

Comment: . Last but not least: In your example, how would I be able to pass any parameters to the triggered function?

Comment: @Thalaia You'd create a wrapper function as the callback and then the callback would call your main function with the parameters. I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: Ok, so that part would be more or less the same way as in my code. The main difference would be to set an eventListener per monitored element, right? Would you recommend the same approach if I had, say, 100 buttons and then just loop through them to add the eventListeners? Would that be acceptable performance wise? 
(Sorry for just asking and not checking myself, but I haven't figured out to best benchmark a solution yet and am not yet able to properly use sites like jsperf)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but it's not working the way it's written right now. Your mapped functions call your handlers with `event.target`, but you never pass `event` when you call the mapped function. The mapped functions need to look like this in order to work:

```
...
b_one: function(event) {
  one(event.target)
}
...
```

... and your invokation of it in the event handler needs to look like this:

```
buttonMap[tar](event)
```

What you're doing, attaching the event listener to the body and invoking a handler based on the event target, is called event delegation. You should add a check to make sure the clicked button really has an associated mapped function in order to make sure it doesn't crash when clicking some other button:

```
if (typeof buttonMap[tar] === 'function') {
  buttonMap[tar](event);
}
```

---

The purpose of running code on the `DOMContentLoaded` is to make sure the code runs after the DOM has been parsed and is available. This can also be accomplished by placing the script block after the DOM elements it's relying on. For instance, at the end of the body element.

Comment: Integrating an error handling is a good idea.
I’m not sure I completely understood all of your answer: You say it’s not working without passing ‘event’, so what is causing the alert in my example to fire and give out the text content of the calling button? In what scenario wouldn’t I get my expected result anymore?

Comment: @Thalaia Since you don't take the `event` object as an argument in the function, the object that gets accessed is `window.event`. This is a non-standard Internet Explorer feature that is implemented by some browsers but not all. Firefox, for instance, doesn't support it and your script will crash with an error saying `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out and explaining it to me. I have to admit, I only tried this in Chrome and Safari (FF and I haven't been friends, since an update caused my favorite add-on to cease working).